# C++ force compiler error if template resolution fails

Tags: c++, templates

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65939204/c-template-based-get) I have the following templated method:

```
...
template <typename T>
const T& get() const {
    if constexpr ( std::is_same_v<T, C1> )
       return this->c1;
    else if constexpr( std::is_same_v<T, C2> )
       return this->c2;
    else
       throw std::logic_error("Tried to lookup from invalid type");
}
```

This works - but in the case of a type which is not represented in the container - e.g. `Container::get<int>` I would like to get a compile time error instead of the `throw std::logic_error()` at runtime. How can I achieve that?

Comment: `static_assert(std::is_same_v<T, C1> || std::is_same_v<T, C2>)` as first line of `get` definition ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53945490/how-to-assert-that-a-constexpr-if-else-clause-never-happen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `static_assert` as

```
template<class T> struct dependent_false : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
const T& get() const {
    if constexpr ( std::is_same_v<T, C1> )
       return this->c1;
    else if constexpr( std::is_same_v<T, C2> )
       return this->c2;
    else
       static_assert(dependent_false<T>::value, "some error message");
}
```